# Where to find flutter windows plugin development information

Tags: windows, flutter, plugins, event-channel

Does Flutter provide any documentation on creating plugins for Windows platform as they do for Android/IOs?

Specifically regarding event channels?

Im trying to develop my first Windows Plugin and have managed to get simple method calls from dart -> native c++ to work, but I'm not sure exactly where to start for method channels.

Several pub.dev projects I've looked are quite complex and a bit overwhelming. Id prefer to not just copy past tons of code I may not need and dont understand. I'm looking for basic examples, preferrably reference implementations from flutter themselves.

Comment: Does this source help you? https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-desktop-plugin-ef8c19cd9ff

Comment: Check out the connectivity plugin - at about line 91 - https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus_windows/windows/connectivity_plus_windows_plugin.cpp